# Using a blockchain type system for different purposes

Tags: blockchain, message

I was wondering, not that I really took the time to investigate much yet but....

Wouldn't it be possible, to do many different things, with the blockchain concept?

Maybe i could build a "browser" which gets its content from a blockchain?

A basic idea is for example, messaging or a chat/email service.
You install the application (just like your qt wallet), you are given a unique address and off you go, now you can send messages.
Messages would then be added to the blockchain and verified by everyone, yet only the person with the correct address can read the message.

This would in theory, be a pretty secure way to send messages.

Comment: Nothing about the blockchain is *secure* with respect to messages. You would have to encrypt the messages somehow (otherwise everybody could read everything), and that adds a whole new level of complexity. However, see [Bitmessage](https://bitmessage.org/wiki/Main_Page) for a P2P communication protocol that is kind of related to these ideas.

Comment: Also research "namecoin" and "mastercoin" for two other applications of the blockchain concept.